# Rails Spree login page not showing, connection refused

Tags: url, routes, capistrano, production, spree

Just managed to deploy a Spree application on a Rackspace Cloud server (Ubuntu 12.04) in production mode. I was using Capistrano and the Spree Deployment Service.

I changed my DNS settings to direct the domain http://opp5.oppermann-london.com to the server's IP address. I can visit the page and URLs such as /products and /cart work, however trying to access the /admin  or /login pages gives the following error on Chrome:

> Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.

I have googled the problem and not found similar issues. Any help would be awesome!

In case this helps, some details:

> Ruby: 1.9.2 p290
>
> Rails 3.2.6
>
> Spree: 1.1.3

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the very same issue. The `/admin` and `/login` require https in production mode by default. Looking at the nginx configuration I can see the https site is not enabled and its configuration points to non-existent certificates anyway.

As a temporary workaround I disabled SSL in `config/initializers/spree.rb` by adding `config.allow_ssl_in_production = false`

Comment: Thanks alot! Did figure it out in the end, but took a long time. Using the same workaround now as well.